# How to mock curry function with Jest?

Tags: jestjs

add.js

```js
export default a => b => a+b;
```

module.js

```js
import add from './add';

export default {
    add1: n => add(1)(n),
};
```

**test**/module.js

```js
import add from '../add';
import module from '../module';

jest.mock('../add', () => () => jest.fn());

module.add1(6);
expect(add.mock.calls).toHaveLength(1);
```

this can be called, but `add` wouldn't be a mock function, instead `add()` is a mock function, but the call params were not recorded correctly.

```
jest.mock('../add', () => () => jest.fn(a => b => a+b));
```

has also tried this, which doesn't seem to work correctly as well.

```
jest.mock('../add', jest.fn(a => b => a+b));
```

this would throw the `inline function` error

Is there a correct way to mock curry function at the moment?

Answer (score 5):

Simple version should look like this

```
jest.mock('../add', () => (a) => jest.fn(b => a+b));
```

So you mock `add` module with a function that return that when gets called it returns the spy, problem you can't test anything on the spy.

So we need to refactor it so you have the `add1` think as a spy in scope of the test

```
import add from '../add'
jest.mock('../add', () => jest.fn)

const addC = jest.fn()
add.mockImplemetation((a) => {
  addC.mockImplementation((b => a+b)
  return addC
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit old but with the following answer I would have saved so much time...

```
import module from "./module";

const mockOperation = {
  add: jest.fn()
};

jest.mock("./add", () => () => {
  return mockOperation.add;
});

describe("add ", () => {
  it("is called at least once", () => {
    module.add1(6);
    expect(mockOperation.add.mock.calls).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

A **very importante thing**: the constant function that you want to mock must start with the word `mock`. Otherwise it will throw an error.

```
const mockOperation = {
  add: jest.fn()
};
```

With the `mockOperation` constant assigned to the add file, by reference is calling to it's `add` method which is a `jest.fn()`

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do this a lot recently so I wrote a helper function to help me out.

```
curryMock = (baseFn, maxCurries) => {
    var callIndex = 0
    var curries = []
    let returnFn

    baseFn.mockImplementation((arg) => {
        curries[callIndex] = 0
        const fn = returnFn(callIndex)
        callIndex++
        return fn
    })

    returnFn = (index: number) => {
        if (curries[index] < maxCurries) {
            curries[index]++
            return (arg: any) => {
                baseFn.mock.calls[index].push(arg)
                return returnFn(index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You pass the function a jest.fn() and `curryMock` modifies it's implementation so that all the arguments return functions are called with will be added to the original `jest.fn().mock.calls` array. The second argument specifies how many times to return a function. `maxCurries = 0` is for a regular function `() => {}`,
maxCurries = 1`is for a regular function`() =>  => {}`, etc.

In your case:

```
import add from '../add';
import module from '../module';

jest.mock('../add');
curryMock(add)

module.add1(6);
expect(add).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1, 6);
//equivalent to
//expect(add).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, 1, 6);

//if you others to test..
module.add7(4)
expect(add).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(2, 7, 4)
```

`curryMock` is a quick utility function that I wrote for personal use. I will likely clean it up and extend it later, but I hope you get the idea: testing curried functions does not have to laborious.